# Magento 1.9 extremely slow admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard, admin-login

We are running an old Magento 1.9.0.1 site which we keep as a data reference. It only allows access via our IPs. Our newer Magento sites are 2.4x and run fine.

Our Magento 1.9.0.1 site has recently started to become extremely slow to login. It takes about 90 seconds to login to the dashboard. Once logged in it works smoothly, as does the frontend. It's just the lag it takes to login to the dashboard.

I've tried disabling all none required modules and slimming the database down as much as possible but neither of these helped improve the login time at all.

Does anyone have any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Consider running this query to identify tables needing OPTIMIZE TABLE table-name;  

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') DATA_Space, 
 CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space, create_time, table_rows, engine, create_options  
 from information_schema.TABLES 
 where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and Data_free > ( DATA_length * .1) 
 ORDER BY FLOOR ( FREE_Space ) DESC, FLOOR ( DATA_Space ) DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
 LIMIT 0,512 
;

Comment: View profile and get in touch, please - if you still need assistance.